# How do I change Feed dialog audience if I have only requested read permissions. It defaults to "Only Me"

Tags: android, ios, facebook, feed

Normally using the feed dialog does not require any publish permissions. However, if I don't ask for any publish permissions (which I'd really rather not), posts made using the feed dialog are visible to "Only Me". There is no way to change the visibility on the mobile platform in the feed dialog itself.
Note: With the new Facebook SDK (3.5) and the Facebook app installed (on Android device) the app actually defaults to whatever defaultAudience I request in my open request. If Facebook app is NOT installed it is just "Only Me" no matter what is in my open request.

It wasn't always like this, and it has actually kind of broken an existing app. Old apps suddenly have the default audience of "Only Me" and the only way the user can change it is by digging through his account settings and finding the app (if he even notices, because it is not shown anywhere but the tiny icon by the post after it is made).

My question is: What am I supposed to do now? Am I forced to request the "publish_actions" permission just to make posts made with the feed dialog visible to a users friends? Seems kind of silly that a user would make posts to his stream that he can only see himself.

Could it be a newly introduced bug in facebook?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem. It has not always been like that. I have filed a bug with FB, maybe you could "upvote" it if it corresponds to your own situation... https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/427850253977806

Comment: @Pascal I filed a bug with FB myself. Looks like yours has been marked as a duplicate of mine. Don't think there's a way to "upvote" a bug though.

Comment: I was able to mark you bug as "I am able to reproduce", so that might count as some sort of upvote... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answers to the questions myself:

Yes, it is a bug. It is being looked at: [Facebook bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/389035004544629)

Until it is fixed: Yes, it is required to ask for publish permissions if you want to make sure feed dialog posts have a visibility that makes sense.